# Database structure for multi user management

Tags: php, database

I am developing a website which will have multiple user interface **admin**, **client**, **public**, I am creating a single table for these users and am separating them only with the value of one field.

**USER**

```
------------------------------
id
username
password
level     Values (0=>admin, 1=>client, 2=>public)
```

Is is appropriate to develop a table structure in such manner, or should I create different table for different level of user.

Comment: looks fine if each user can only be of one level

Comment: No problems with that if you take other security precautions. Really the simplest (and most common) solution to have all users in a single table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend that you create a separate table for user levels. This will allow for a user to level relationship and allow for seamless and efficient updates.

```
user
----
id
username
password
level_id (fk)

userLevel
----
id
level
```